# How to update value in laravel blade ui without refresh the page

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i need some help. I want to make my tables update the status when i click refresh button. But can i make it without refreshing the page? Like just the value on the table that updated. Something like re-render in javascript when there is an update to the state..

Comment: You can do it by using jquery. After CRUD operation, render table as `html` and return it as response to frontend. Once you got rendered html in frontend you will need to remove current table from html and put rendered one.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to accomplish what you are asking... some examples here:

- You could use a javascript ajax that ask for the updated table and
  reload it when you click refresh.
- You could use a javascript ajax that ask only for changes and update
  only changed fields.
- You could set and Interval with setInterval that ask for changed
  values automatically.
- **For something more tricky**: you could manage a serverSocket for push updates to client and trigger javascript to manage the updating
  data